# How to implement this iteration/convergence step by guessing a value in Matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, iteration, implementation

I have two parameters `fL and fV`, both functions of T and P. If I make a function called `func(T)`, which takes only `T` as input, then how do I go about implementing this step in Matlab:

```
Guess P

if |(fL/fV)-1|<0.0001 % where fL and fV are both functions of T and P

then print P

else P=P*(fL/fV)
```

Initially it is advised to guess the `P` in the beginning of the algorithm. All other steps before this involve formula calculation and doesn't involve any converging, so I didn't write all those formulas. The important thing to note is even though we take only `T` as input for our function, the pressure is guessed in the beginning of the code and is not part of any input by the user.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "guess" `P`, you can either proceed using a) an educated guess or b) a random guess. So, for example if you were dealing with pressure in the day to day surroundings, `100kPa` would be a reasonable guess. A random guess would mean initializing `P` to a random variable generated over a meaningful domain. So in my example, it could be a random variable uniformly distributed between `90kPa` and `110kPa`. Which of these approaches you choose depends on your specific problem.

You can code your requirements as follows

```
minP=90;maxP=110;
P=minP+(maxP-minP)*rand;%# a random guess between 90 & 100 

<some code here where you calculate fL and fV

if abs(fL/fV-1)<0.0001
    fprintf('%f',P)
else
    P=P*fL/fV;
end
```